# How can I pass a List<String> from a REST component to a custom cloud connector in Mule?

Tags: list, rest, esb, mule

I have a custom cloud connector with a function that takes a List.  Hard-coding the values into the connector's properties works fine, but how can I pass a URL with ?listitem=item1&listitem=item2&other=other through a REST component, a Choice flow controller, and to my cloud connector.

When I tell put #[header:inbound:listitem] in the connectors "From Message" field, I get:

sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class (java.lang.ClassCastException)

I think it is looking for a string and accepts only the first listitem, even though my REST component recognized it as a LIST and logs both.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
Sorry, I typed it up in a hurry.
The Cloud Connector processor method is:

```
@Processor
    public void renewSubscriptionMultiple(List<String> uuids, String hours)throws Exception{
        for(String uuid:uuids){
            uuid = URLDecoder.decode(uuid,ENCODING);
        }
        hours = URLDecoder.decode(hours, ENCODING);     
        logger.info("Renewing subscriptions: "+uuids+" for "+hours+" hours");
                renewSubscriptions(uuids,hours);
    }
```

It just decodes them and passes them to another method.  I dont this this is the problem   because I am able to pass a hardcoded list fine.

My query is 
myIP:8081/test/subscriptions-renew?uuids=uuids1&uuids=uuids2&hours=24

And the Mule version is 3.3.0

Comment: There are many unclear points here: the header expression expects "listitems" while the query parameters are "listitem" and "listitem2". Also the casting seems to happen towards a `java.lang.Class` not a `java.util.List`. So please show the Cloud Connector processor method, the Mule configuration that uses it and the exact query use to test the flow. Also specify the Mule version.